# What is the difference between одолеть and преодолеть?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

Looking in the dictionary, **одолеть** and **преодолеть** both share pretty much the same meanings. So is there any substantial difference between the two or are they interchangeable?

Comment: The thing is, the meanings do not quite match. "Одолеть" is focused on defeating, overpowering someone/something. Sometimes literally.  "Преодолеть" (with its prefix пре-) is more like getting over to "the other side" despite all the difficulties. Overcoming these difficulties and moving on. Here the difficulties are never a person and are viewed as an _obstacle_ rather than a _rival_ to be defeated.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Преодолевать-преодолеть" is more widely used than "одолевать-одолеть" in the sense of "overcome". For example, "to overcome difficulties" is better translated as "преодолеть трудности" than "одолеть трудности".

However, the verb "одолевать-одолеть" has two meanings, that the verb "преодолевать-преодолеть" doesn't have. The first one is **"to defeat smb"**:

Он меня одолел.
He defeated me.

The second one is **"to be possessed, overwhelmed by a feeling"**:

Его одолела тоска.
He was overwhelmed by melancholy.

Comment: Thank you Russian Teacher! That's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting questions that make me analyse my own language!

Comment: Here's another one for you: what does it mean when people say жить можно? I saw a Russian show with two guys coming out of a store after having bought all kinds of gadgets and one of them said that.

Comment: It is something like "We are going to live well now" (having all these gadgets. There's also another synonymic expression, "живём".

Answer (score 2):

одолеть = to win over somebody, defeat

преодолеть = to overcome (an obstacle, hurdle, etc).